# How to count the doctors that do not have bookings by patients?

Tags: php, mysql, count

The result should look like:

```
Doctors_have_no_patients
Doctor2
Doctor3
Doctor5
```

THE TABLES

```
Doctor table called `Doctors`
**DoctorID**
Doctor1
Doctor2
Doctor3
Doctor4
Doctor5


Booking table called `Bookings`

PatientID  DoctorID  Date
Patient1   Doctor1   etc.
Patient2   Doctor4   etc.
Patient3   Doctor1   etc.
```

Should I use `distinct` or something? Like:

`select Bookings.DoctorID as Doctors_have_no_patients count(distinct(Bookings.PatientID))...`

Comment: you need to use `distinct` in your `bookings` select as you wrote @Tews

Answer (score 2):

You can use not in (and no distinct in this case)

Number of doctors without patients

```
select count(*) from Doctors
where DoctorId not in (select doctorID from bookings);
```

Id of doctors

```
select DoctorID from Doctors
where DoctorId not in ( select doctorID from bookings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
   SELECT * from `Doctors`
    WHERE `DoctorID` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(`doctorID`) FROM `bookings`);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use the following"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.